# Magento 1.7 Mage::()->getModel() don't work

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have problem with save records in database using Mage::getModel in module upgrade.

I'd like add affiliate programs to affiliateplus module table when my module is installed. My module overwrite affiliateplus module.

In mysql4-upgrade-0.1.3-0.1.4.php I have code

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$_programList =[
    'affiliate'=>[
            'program_id'=>1,
            'name' =>'Program Afiliacyjny',
            'created_date' =>date('Y-m-d'),
            'status' =>1,
            'expire_time'=>0,
            'num_account'=>2,
            'total_sales_amount' =>0.00,
            'commission_type'=>'precentage',
            'commission'=>1,
            'discount_type'=>'precentage',
            'discount' =>1,
            'autojoin' =>1,
            'scope' =>0,
            'customer_groups' =>null,
            'show_in_welcome' =>0,
            'valid_from' =>null,
            'valid_to' =>null,
            'use_coupon' =>0,
            'coupon_pattern'=>null ,
            'affiliate_type'=>null ,
            'description' =>'Program Afiliacyjny',
            'conditions_serialized' =>'a:6:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}',
            'actions_serialized' =>'a:6:{s:4:"type";s:40:"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}',
            'is_process' =>0,
            'use_tier_config'=>0 ,
            'max_level' =>0,
            'tier_commission'=>null ,
            'sec_commission' =>0,
            'sec_commission_type'=>0 ,
            'secondary_commission' =>0,
            'sec_discount' =>0,
            'sec_discount_type'=>null ,
            'secondary_discount' =>0,
            'customer_group_ids' =>'1',
            'use_sec_tier' =>0,
            'sec_tier_commission'=>null
    ],
    ['more elements...']
];

foreach($_programList as $_v){
    $_program = Mage::getModel('affiliateplusprogram/program');
    $_program->setData($_v);
    $_program->save();

    unset($_program);
}
$installer->endSetup();
```

I tryed also:

- foreach inside loop and setData for each value.
- setId() before save

When I display object after foreach it's object with only my values without methods. 
Magento don't show errors and warnings. My module is upgrade to good version but in database table is empty.

In all tutorials solve id simple Mage::getModel ->setData()->save()

Answer (score 0):

hard so say, why savin isn't working. i would

1) clear whole magento cache

if this helps not, add a record to your database and try to load it, or write a single object to database using setter Methods of your model. if you cannot load / save any entities, try to debug, if all the affiliateplusprogram/program Model are instanciated correctly.

Comment: Thank for answer. Cache of course is clear.
Code
`$_program = Mage::getModel('affiliateplusprogram/program')->load(2);
$_name = $_program->getName();
$_name = 'Program Afiliacyjny plus';
$_program->setName($_name);
$_program->save();`
Working. But new record not.

Comment: Have you already checked all of your Models? e.g. Model, Mysql4 Model an Collection Model?

Comment: Models are done from affiliate plus module. It's comercial model. I use models from this module.
I modified loop on

`foreach($_programList as $_v){
    $_program = Mage::getModel('affiliateplusprogram/program');
    foreach($_v as $_key=>$_val){
        $_program->{'set'.ucfirst($_key)}($_val);
    }

    $_program->save();

    unset($_program);
}
`
but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. What if replace foreach loop with:

```
foreach($_programList as $_v){
  Mage::getModel('affiliateplusprogram/program')
    ->setData($_v)
    ->save();
}
```

(without unset()), will it work? I met a problem no saving model if call exit; right after $model->save();

Comment: Add exit is helpfull because is transaction error. But if autojoin field is 0. When I using admin panel filled is one table. I don't know why is rolback.

Comment: Maybe it stupid question but - check you _beforeSave methods in affiliated plus module - models, collections? They can interrupt the process of saving.

Comment: Yes I checked _beforeSave.
0
Now I don't wase my time and I created own modle for this table. 

And when I have code

`foreach($_programList as $_v){

    $_program = Mage::getModel('unizeto_partner/affiliateplusprogram');



    foreach($_v as $_key=>$_val){


        $_program->{'set'.ucfirst($_key)}($_val);

    }

    $_program->save();



}` 
can't work. When I remove $_val data is set with default values to database. I don't know why

Comment: Why not `$_program->setData($_key, $_val);`?

Comment: Exists in the install or update scripts of the Affiliate Plus triggers, stored procedures, etc?

Comment: No. Now it's working but after remove program_id which is primary key and auto increment field.

I'd like overwrite autoincrement value but not disable autoincrement only for this one operation, not for all operations on this model.

Comment: Yes, it's impossible :). But you can change primary key into the your models' and collection's settings to another field and Magento will allow us update the older "primary" field. If mysql allow it of course.

Comment: But if I change primary key into my models that I can't change value of other field. If I'm right?